# Can we set dynamic image size of slack message?

Tags: java, json, slack, slack-api

I am building something and I need to set dynamic image size of slack message JSON image. Below is the JSON which I have created.

```
{
    "text":"This will be header",
    "attachments": [
        {       
            "thumb_url":"https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/7/76/Slack_Icon.png",
            "fields": [
                {
                    "title": "Title",
                    "value": "123",
                    "short": true
                }
            ],
            "color": "#F35A00"
        }
    ]
}
```

In the above JSON, I want to set the custom size for **thumb_url** but I can't find the property for that. Can someone have any idea about it?

Answer (score 1):

No, you can not set a custom size for the thumbnail image in attachments.